# In Apache spark, how does Apache ignite deploy itself on all worker nodes with dynamic executor being enabled in spark

Tags: apache-spark, ignite

I went through the code for IgniteContext, with mode as deploy ignite on all executor nodes, I found that the ignite instance is deployed internally in all executors with the help of spark context parallize method, the ignite instance is stopped using spark event listeners ( viz. on application end). I couldn't figure out whether ignite gets deployed on dynamically added spark executors ? I couldn't find any such code in IgniteContext. Can some one comment on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Checked the ignite code to find out that ignite executes a task on all the executor nodes. The task deploys ignite if not already deployed on the executor node of spark.

Additionally it attaches an event listener to check if a new executor node is spawned and if spawned again runs the same task on that node. On application end, it stops the ignite instance.